# giving error in mssql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fetch records by group_by clause in mssql but it is giving me an error like -

> Column '`SYWOTP.dbo.MLPurchaseOrder.POID`' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Following is my query...

```
SELECT "MLPurchaseOrder"."POID",  "MLPurchaseOrder"."PONumber",    "MLPurchaseOrder"."CreatedDate",  "MLPurchaseOrderDetails"
."POID" as "MapperPOID",  "MLStorageSystem"."ProductID",       "ProductMaster"."ProductName", "ProductEntityMapper"
."ActualPriceUSD"
FROM "SYWOTP"."dbo"."MLPurchaseOrder"
JOIN "SYWOTP"."dbo"."MLPurchaseOrderDetails" ON   "MLPurchaseOrderDetails"."POID" = "MLPurchaseOrder"."POID"

JOIN "SYWOTP"."dbo"."MLStorageSystem" ON   "MLStorageSystem"."MLStorageID"   = "MLPurchaseOrderDetails"."MLStorageID"

JOIN "ExBMPCatalog"."dbo"."ProductMaster" ON "ProductMaster"."ProductID" = "MLStorageSystem"."ProductID"

JOIN "ExBMPCatalog"."dbo"."ProductEntityMapper" ON   "ProductEntityMapper"."productID" = "MLStorageSystem"
."ProductID"
WHERE "ProductMaster"."MerchantID" = 2
AND "MLStorageSystem"."EXBWarehouseID" IS NULL
AND "MLPurchaseOrderDetails"."BatchHash" IS NULL
OR "MLPurchaseOrderDetails"."BatchHash" = ''
GROUP BY "ExBMPCatalog"."dbo"."ProductMaster"."ProductID"
ORDER BY "ProductName" ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

any help would be great...thnxx in advance: )

Comment: Two options you have - either use all the columns you have in `SELECT` in `GROUP BY` too or use Aggregate Function in the columns you deem to use in `SELECT` and then rest of the columns you can specify in `GROUP BY`
a good read - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please use proper alias to avoid code complexity. You should add all the columns in the select statement to Group by or It seems you have not used any aggregate function in your select so you can simply use Distinct.

Try like this,

Using Group by:

```
SELECT MLPO.POID
    ,MLPO.PONumber
    ,MLPO.CreatedDate
    ,MLPOD.POID AS MapperPOID
    ,MLSS.ProductID
    ,PM.ProductName
    ,PEM.ActualPriceUSD
FROM SYWOTP.dbo.MLPurchaseOrder MLPO
JOIN SYWOTP.dbo.MLPurchaseOrderDetails MLPOD ON MLPOD.POID = MLPO.POID
JOIN SYWOTP.dbo.MLStorageSystem MLSS ON MLSS.MLStorageID = MLPOD.MLStorageID
JOIN ExBMPCatalog.dbo.ProductMaster PM ON PM.ProductID = MLSS.ProductID
JOIN ExBMPCatalog.dbo.ProductEntityMapper PEM ON PEM.productID = MLSS.ProductID
WHERE PM.MerchantID = 2
    AND MLSS.EXBWarehouseID IS NULL
    AND MLPOD.BatchHash IS NULL
    OR MLPOD.BatchHash = ''
GROUP BY MLPO.POID
    ,MLPO.PONumber
    ,MLPO.CreatedDate
    ,MLPOD.POID
    ,MLSS.ProductID
    ,PM.ProductName
    ,PEM.ActualPriceUSD
ORDER BY ProductName ASC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Using Distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MLPO.POID
    ,MLPO.PONumber
    ,MLPO.CreatedDate
    ,MLPOD.POID AS MapperPOID
    ,MLSS.ProductID
    ,PM.ProductName
    ,PEM.ActualPriceUSD
FROM SYWOTP.dbo.MLPurchaseOrder MLPO
JOIN SYWOTP.dbo.MLPurchaseOrderDetails MLPOD ON MLPOD.POID = MLPO.POID
JOIN SYWOTP.dbo.MLStorageSystem MLSS ON MLSS.MLStorageID = MLPOD.MLStorageID
JOIN ExBMPCatalog.dbo.ProductMaster PM ON PM.ProductID = MLSS.ProductID
JOIN ExBMPCatalog.dbo.ProductEntityMapper PEM ON PEM.productID = MLSS.ProductID
WHERE PM.MerchantID = 2
    AND MLSS.EXBWarehouseID IS NULL
    AND MLPOD.BatchHash IS NULL
    OR MLPOD.BatchHash = ''

ORDER BY ProductName ASC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

You group by

```
"ExBMPCatalog"."dbo"."ProdcutMaster".
```

But your table seems to be

```
"ExBMPCatalog"."dbo"."ProductMaster
```

Always use aliases,this makes code readable as well

Comment: my table name is ProductMaster and column name is ProductID

Comment: I put following  GROUP BY "ExBMPCatalog"."dbo"."ProductMaster"."ProductID"  and it worked but gave this error -- Column 'SYWOTP.dbo.MLPurchaseOrder.POID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.